# Drop a column from a delimited file and save it to existing filename

Tags: unix, awk, cut

Do anyone know how to drop a column from hundreds of columns and save it to the existing file name? And I have to do it for several files also, is it possible I can do it together at the same time? I have been looking and trying for it but it seems no luck with it. 
Thanks for those who can help.

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=x)f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}' x=2 file > file1
```

Is this the correct one?

Answer (score 2):

Your `awk` code looks good.  However, `cut` may be your best friend if you want to speed things up:

```
# let's say we want to take out column number 2
for file in *; do
  newfile="$file.changed"
  cut -f1,3- -d, "$file" > "$newfile" && mv "$newfile" "$file"
done
```

---

Here is an `awk` vs `cut` comparison for a file with 2.4 million identical lines like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6

time awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=x)f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}' x=2 t >/dev/null

real    0m13.815s
user    0m13.116s
sys 0m0.217s

time cut -f1,3- -d, t >/dev/null

real    0m2.374s
user    0m2.093s
sys 0m0.054s
```

---

The rule of thumb I use is this - `awk` is for things that can't be done with `cut`, `sed`, `paste` etc., and files involved are small.  If performance is important or if there is complex logic, always opt for a better language like Perl, Python, or Ruby which help us write more readable code.

Comment: I tried it out but it doesn't work out. I want to remove second column so I just changed it to -1,3- right? Thanks

Comment: For the second column, `1,3-`

Comment: it worked successfully but second column is still there. Did I left out anything?

Comment: `cut -f1,3- -d, <<< "1,2,3,4,5"` gives `1,3,4,5`.

Comment: Thank you so much @codeforester ! Let me try it out the suggestion you give. Appreciate it!

Comment: Is it possible I can cut second column from all files and name it back to the same separate files?



          `cut -d'|' -f 1,3- ABC.csv > ABC.csv`

@codeforester

Comment: For example, I want to cut second column from all 5 files, after cutting replace it back to separate files back. So I get all five flies with no second columns in the end. Is it possible I can do it together?

Comment: Actually, my answer was supposed to do that.  There was a typo that would have prevented.  Just corrected it.  However, you can do `cut ... ABC.csv > ABC.csv` - that will destroy your file.